# Angular2 Template syntax - How to do a OR on ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to loop though a list and want to show and element based on id.

If I do

```
*ngIf="environment.id!=3" then works.
```

cell is hidden.  But I want to do

```
*ngIf="environment.id!=3 OR environment.id!=1"
```

which does not work.

```
<tr *ngFor="let environment of environments">
          <td>{{ environment.name }}</td>
          <td>
              <a *ngIf="environment.id!=3 ? environment.id!=1" [routerLink]="['EditEnvironment', { id: environment.id }]">
                      <i class="icon icon-edit"></i>
              </a>
          </td>
                <td>
            <i (click)="deleteEnvironment(environment)" class="icon icon-cross"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
*ngIf="environment.id!=3 || environment.id!=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

This `*ngIf` is **always** `true` because every value is either `!= 3` or `!= 1`

```
 *ngIf="environment.id!=3 OR environment.id!=1"
```

- `2` is != 3 and also != 1
- `1` is != 3
- `3` is != 1

With `OR` only one needs to match.

You might want

```
     *ngIf="!(environment.id==3 || environment.id==1)"
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SStFNIF1qrewfXjHQU8t?p=preview)